# Animated sound waveform

Tags: code-golf

Make an animated sound waveform using any programming language your prefer, the squares of the spectrum can be of a single color (no rainbow effect).
The animation must be infinite and not a loop sequence (must be a random animation).

You can use any kind of external library you prefer.

This is a code-golf so the shortest code will win.

Example of waveform:
[image]

(a screenshot of the result is appreciated)

Edit:
I thought was obvious,but the waveform must be horizontal.

Comment: I think the winning answer is going to look quite unlike your example unless you at least specify minimum numbers of segments in the horizontal and vertical directions and a minimum number of frames before the animation repeats. Even then, the results won't be very realistic if the values in each channel are changed randomly.

Comment: This is not a spectrum. Did you mean "waveform" or "bar plot"?

Comment: Didn't know the exact name,thanks

Comment: Define "infinite"; PRNGs can have periods anywhere from 2^32 to 2^19934, both of which aren't quite infinite.

Answer (score 3):

### APL (61)

```
{∇n⊣⎕DL.1⊣⎕SM←1 1,⍨⊂' '⍪⊖⍉↑⍴∘'▇'¨,0,⍪n←24⌊0⌈⍵+3-?5/⍨⍴⍵}?24/40
```

It starts with random-sized bars, and changes the height of each of the bars by a random number between -2 and 2 each frame.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `INVALID TOKEN` trying with tryapl?

Comment: @FezVrasta: Use Dyalog APL. TryAPL is very limited, my guess is most of the APL code on this site won't run there.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 96

The program takes two arguments which are the height and width of the "graphics", so to make it fill a 80x24 terminal, run it with `ruby spectrum.rb 80 24`

```
w,h=$*.map &:to_i
loop{o=(1..w).map{rand h}
h.times{|i|puts o.map{|j|j>i ?" ":?#}*''}
sleep 0.1}
```

Displays something like this in the terminal:

```
       #            
       #            
     ###  #         
  #  ###  #         
  ## ###  ##        
  ## #### ##        
 ######## ##        
######### ##       #
######### ##      ##
######### ##      ##
######### ##   #####
#############  #####
#############  #####
####################
```

## Ruby 22

With horizontal bars and fixed width (heigh = height of terminal)

```
loop{puts ?#*rand(24)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash and Linux utils, 79

The question specifications are a little imprecise, so here is my vertically-scrolling ascii-art interpretation that uses real sound input samples (much more interesting than random data)

```
arecord -q|xxd -g1 -c1|while read _ s _;do printf "%$[0x$s-88]s
"|tr " " =;done
```

Output for a few milliseconds of Rachmaninov's Piano Concerto #2:

```
=========================================
======================================
=======================================
===========================================
========================================
======================================
========================================
=========================================
========================================
======================================
========================================
==========================================
========================================
======================================
=========================================
=========================================
```

Comment: well.. the example is horizontal actually.

Comment: @FezVrasta - True, though it wasn't explicitly stated.  Horizontal scrolling will be ***much*** harder in just about any ascii-art environment.  I was more interested in this for the fun of using real sound input samples

Answer (score 0):

### Batch - 193

```
@echo off&setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
:s
set/ar=%RANDOM%*17/32768+4&for /l %%a in (20,-1,1)do (if %%a GEQ %r% (set l%%a= !l%%a!) else set l%%a=Û!l%%a!)&echo !l%%a!
ping 1>nul&cls&@goto s
```

Un-golfed -

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
:s
set /a r=%RANDOM%*17/32768+4
for /l %%a in (20,-1,1) do (
    if %%a GEQ %r% (set l%%a= !l%%a!) else set l%%a=Û!l%%a!
) & echo !l%%a!
ping 1>nul
cls
goto s
```

This will work assuming you have an infinitely wide terminal window - I'll work on the text wrapping...

Not the prettiest - but it does the trick - **295 bytes**

```
@echo off&setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2" %%w in ('mode con^|findstr Col')do set w=%%w
:s
mode con:cols=%w% lines=20
set/ar=%RANDOM%*17/32768+4&for /l %%a in (20,-1,1)do (if %%a GEQ %r% (set l%%a= !l%%a!) else set l%%a=Û!l%%a!)&echo !l%%a!
set/aw+=1&ping 1>nul&cls&@goto s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 105

This animates continually, at approximately 24 frames per second, as if it were capturing sound in real-time. However, it is not processing sound at all.  (That would would require considerably more code.)

```
data1@n_ := NormalDistribution[0, 1]~RandomVariate~150;
Animate[Histogram[data1@a, Axes -> False], {a, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab (43 / 37)

```
while(1)hist(randn(100,1));pause(1/24);end
```

Inspired by the Mathematica approach, this is just a histogram of 100 random, normally distributed numbers. the plot regenerates at 1/24 second per frame (24 fps).
[image: Histogram Version]

Shorter, Stranger version (37):

```
while(1)bar(randn(9,1));pause(.1);end
```

This version includes negative numbers, so it doesn't exactly fit the requirements.
[image: Bar version]